# Did Juventus sell 520,000 (or about €54M worth of) Ronaldo jerseys within 24 hours?

Tags: sport, marketing

I am not familiar with football jersey sales and these numbers seem remarkably high to me, hence my skepticism.

[Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2018/jul/16/cristiano-ronaldo-joins-juventus-real-madrid-portugal-turin):

> Within 24 hours of his transfer being made official last Tuesday, Juventus had sold 520,000 shirts with his name on.

[Yahoo Italy](https://it.notizie.yahoo.com/ronaldo-un-giorno-vendute-520-mila-maglie-094159968.html) (Google translated):

> **Ronaldo, in one day sold 520 thousand jerseys**
>
> The price? For the commercial version 104 euros , 1 44.90 for the official replica. At the moment it is not clear whether yesterday's sales concern the first or second version, but little changes. ...
>
> Let's assume, on the downside, that all the links are those in the commercial version. That is, those from 104 euros. For 520 thousand times it means gross income of around 54 million euros.

Comment: I would focus on the number of jerseys sold, and disregard their price or "gross income". Because that way a thorough answer would not have to go through the motions of cautioning that it does also *cost* something to have those jerseys produced and marketed...

Comment: and remember sold could mean ordered - delivery may take some time...